# Automation using selenium (java)

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check if my filter is resulting into empty grid(not rows). The GUI doesn't have any table to check empty rows. It's getting data at run time. Can somebody please help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code and describe problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filter does not return any data then you can check size of `//table` `tagName` which will return 0 as elements will not be there in DOM

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table")).size()==0){
System.out.println(" No data returned")
}
else 
System.out.println(" Data returned and table is present at run time")
```

Comment: import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\vd53313.IND\Desktop\testing.xlsx')

df.loc[((df.spin== 'sor') | (df.spin== r'f/r')), 'mtm' ] = df["mtm"] + df["wes"] *100000

writer =pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\vd53313.IND\Desktop\output.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

writer.save()

Comment: https://javaconceptoftheday.com/java-interview-programs-with-solutions/